# PyQGIS 3 commit error with a PostGIS table on a nextval() column

Tags: pyqgis-3, postgis-2.0

I'm working on QGIS3.14.15 and I'm trying to update a PostGIS table with features comming from another table (`pg_actual`) and I have an error:

> ERROR: 14 feature(s) not added.
>  Provider errors:    PostGIS error
> while adding features: ERROR:  null value in column "gid" violates
> not-null constraint

The "gid" field is defined as SERIAL, so it is not null and has a default value nextval(sequence foo):

```
gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pg_add_table_gid_seq'::regclass),
```

That's not the first time I'm avoiding a `gid` field and I'm used to see it auto incrementing by the provider after the `commitChanges()` method.

```
fields_actuals = pg_actual.fields()
list_add = []
geom_old = [oldFeat['ident'] for oldFeat in pg_old.getFeatures()]
fields_add = pg_add.fields()
for actFeat in pg_actual.getFeatures():
    if actFeat['ident'] not in geom_old:
        list_add.append(actFeat)
if len(list_add):
    print("New data:")
    pg_add.startEditing()
    for actFeat in list_add:
        actFeat2 = QgsFeature(fields_add)
        for field in fields_actuals:
            if field.name() != 'gid':
                actFeat2[field.name()] = actFeat[field.name()]
        actFeat2.setGeometry(actFeat.geometry())
        pg_add.addFeature(actFeat2)
    res = pg_add.commitChanges()
    if not res:
        print("Commit failed.")
        for err in pg_add.commitErrors():
            writeLog(err)
    else:
        print("commit OK!")
```

Comment: Let me know if `layer.dataProvider().defaultValue(gid_idx)` (where gid_idx is the index of your `gid` field) gives you something different from `NULL`. Depending on your response, I'll elaborate a more complete answer below.

Comment: I printed 
        print(pg_add.dataProvider().defaultValue(fields_add.indexFromName('gid'))) and i had the result 'None'

Comment: I loaded manualy the layer and I saw it has no key. I add a primary key to the gid: gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, it solved the gid autocompletion problem but I have a problem for a second column I declared as serial, aka not null + nextval on a sequence.

Comment: QGIS is highly configurable. Through the Settings menu, it provides an option to evaluate provider's delfaults values as told here:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330439/handling-postgis-id-column-in-qgis